# Unsure why AHK script isn't working as intended

Tags: autohotkey

I use chrome bookmarks a lot, and I also often have to send people screen snippets very often, however I don't want all my bookmarks on display (some are sorta private). I know I could add them to the Other Bookmarks folder, but would rather easy access. What I've been doing for a while is hitting the bookmark shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+B), then the snipping tool (WIN+SHIFT+S), taking my screenshot and then putting the Bookmarks back (CTRL+SHIFT+B). Eventually I decided to bite the bullet and spend some time automating it, so that hitting CTRL+SHIFT+S would close the Bookmark Bar, and letting go of the mouse (after taking the clipping) would put it back. This is what I came up with:

```
~#+s:: Send, ^+B
KeyWait, LButton, D
Send, ^+B
return
```

Although the first half works (Bookmarks go away, snipping tools open) at no point does the bar return. I've tried many things including setting up a timer, and waiting for the space bar instead of the mouse button, which i'd only hit when ready. I have also tested, and manually pressing the keys immediately after letting go the mouse button did indeed re-open the Bookmarks.

Would anyone be able to explain why this is happening? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you put the first command on the same line as the hotkey definition.
This will create a one liner hotkey and the rest of the code below wont run.

Second problem is that you're sending the input to show bookmarks again while the screenshotting window is active. You're going to want to wait until chrome is active again.
This works:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
~#+s:: 
    SendInput, ^+b
    Sleep, 2000
    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    SendInput, ^+b
return
#IfWinActive
```

A bit of sleep so the screenshot window has time to open, and also added in `#IfWinActive`, because I'd assume you only want that hotkey to be active while you're on chrome.
Also switched over to [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) and made the `b` lower case. Having it as uppercase would send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (on most keyboard layouts).